# use .htaccess to redirect all requests but two

Tags: .htaccess

I am new to this but I have the following .htaccess that works correctly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /wordpress [L,R=301]
```

This redirects anyone at site.com or www.site.com to go to www.site.come/wordpress
However I have 2 directories that I need to ignore this rule:
www.site.com/dir1
www.site.com/dir2
and these need to be ignored (not re-written even if they come without the www.)

*Edit:* It needs to ignore the directory AND files in the directory.
so site.com/dir1 AND site.com/dir1/index.php should both be left alone.

How can I do this?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a couple more conditions to your first RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir1(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir2(/|$)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /wordpress [L,R=301]
```

The `(/|$)` at the end of the conditions tests for either a / for another path component, or the end of the request (`$`).  You could leave the `(/|$)` off if you're not particular and are willing to ignore any request starting with `/dir1` or `/dir2`, e.g. `/dir1a`.

The second RewriteRule doesn't need any new conditions, since it only matches the domain root (`^$`).

Comment: Exactly what I needed and I REALLY appreciate the explanation!